# Use Excel as a modal spreadsheet control in Word?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

As an alternative to either using any of the no longer extant Grid or Spreadsheet controls or attempting to write my own in VBA (lousy and primitive) I thought to try to use Excel itself as a kind of GridView control.  The idea would be to attempt to replicate a kind of modal dialogue box.  I need this to work from Word.  So far I got this far:

```
Public Function xlmat() As Variant

    Dim xl As Excel.Application: Set xl = New Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook: Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Add
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    Dim r As Variant
    xl.ShowStartupDialog = False
    xl.Visible = True
    ws.Activate

    On Error GoTo islands

    While -1 <> xl.ActiveSheet.Columns.Count
        r = xl.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value
        Sleep 1000
        DoEvents
    Wend

islands:
    Set ws = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set xl = Nothing
    xlmat = r

End Function
```

Third party controls and the like are right out.

The idea is that the code starts up an Excel instance (that much works) and then the user would enter whatever data and close Excel.  In a loop, the code attempts to determine that Excel is finally dead, closed by the user.  The result of the latest result of `xl.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value` would be whatever the user entered and the result of the function.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: So, if you run this function in a loop it's going to create *n* instances of the Excel application in memory which are never cleaned up. Eventually, something is going to crash. And for modal you'd need the Windows API. Perhaps you should research the term "Dictator application" in regards to Excel. Replace all but the functionality the user needs in the UI and take full control. If it's modal, the user won't be able to work in Word until he uses your interface to dismiss the Excel window.

Comment: @CindyMeister Thanks for your comment and reference to "Dictator" application.  Cleanup noted.  For now, this would run two consecutive instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following to implement a modal Excel callable from Word.  Its one disadvantage is that it needs a tiny Excel addin to function.  The contents of the Excel addin are two subs which are called when the `OK` and `Cancel` buttons are pressed.  These would be stored in a module called `Modal`.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub doCancel()
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("rc") = 1
End Sub
Public Sub doOk()
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.CustomDocumentProperties("rc") = 2
End Sub
```

The function which invokes modal Excel from Word is the following:

```
Option Explicit
```

First, the sleep function

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMs As LongPtr) ' 64 bit
#Else
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMs As Long) ' 32 bit
#End If
```

The `xlmat` function, started in the question.  Best of all, no usage of VBA error handling.

```
Public Function xlmat() As String
```

Start up Excel

```
    Dim xl As Excel.Application: Set xl = New Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook: Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Add
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    Dim addin As Excel.addin
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Dim rc As Integer
    Dim r As String
    Dim t As Variant
    Dim ec(-1 To 0) As String: ec(-1) = ",": ec(0) = ";"
```

Prepare Excel for modal use.  "Dictator" application code would go here

```
    xl.ScreenUpdating = False
    xl.ShowStartupDialog = False
    xl.Visible = True
    ws.Activate
```

The `OK` and `Cancel` buttons on the spreadsheet.

```
    ws.Buttons.Add 500, 160, 50, 25
    ws.Buttons.Add 500, 260, 50, 25
```

The addin itself has to be loaded.  I called it `ExcelModal.xlam`.

```
    For i = 1 To xl.AddIns.Count
        If xl.AddIns(i).Name = "ExcelModal.xlam" Then
            xl.AddIns(i).Installed = False
            xl.AddIns(i).Installed = True
        End If
    Next i
```

Assign captions and actions to the buttons.  Note the addin is called from here.

```
    ws.Buttons(1).Caption = "Cancel"
    ws.Buttons(1).OnAction = "Modal.doCancel"

    ws.Buttons(2).Caption = "OK"
    ws.Buttons(2).OnAction = "Modal.doOk"
```

I could have parked this value on an Excel cell, but I prefer parking the data
somewhere the user can't get to it.

```
    wb.CustomDocumentProperties.Add Name:="rc", LinkToContent:=False, _
        Type:=MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeNumber, Value:=0
```

Excel spreadsheet starts to become usable here

```
    xl.ScreenUpdating = True
```

This loop has the effect of making Excel modal.  When one of the buttons are 
pressed, `wb.CustomDocumentProperties("rc")` is no longer zero and the loop exits

```
    While 0 = wb.CustomDocumentProperties("rc")
        Sleep 500
        DoEvents
    Wend
```

Depending on the value of rc, return either an empty string when Cancel pressed, or return a flattened string version of whatever was in the spreadsheet.  Works for me.

```
    rc = wb.CustomDocumentProperties("rc")
    xlmat = ""
    If rc = 2 Then
        t = ws.UsedRange.Value
        For i = 1 To UBound(t, 1)
            n = UBound(t, 2)
            For j = 1 To n
                r = r & t(i, j) & ec(j <> n)
            Next j
        Next i
        xlmat = Left(r, Len(r) - 1)
    End If
```

Close up and clean up

```
    wb.Close False
    xl.Quit

    Set ws = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set xl = Nothing

End Function
```

I would be interested in suggestions to eliminate the need of the Excel addin.